# exposing disk usage metrics spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, micrometer

i want to expose the disk usage for my micro-service to Prometheus, i'm already using micrometer and micrometer Prometheus with jdk 11 and spring boot actuator

im able to get all the other metrics working like tomcat_sessions and jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes etc,
and i can't seem to find a way of exposing the disk usage

Comment: I found this open issue https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/549 Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: something like that but that doesn't seem to be merge so what im asking is there a custom endpoint some has already created ?